Next.js Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information) error
I've deployed my Next.js project to Vercel. I've correctly set NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL in the Environment Variables tab to fetch my data, but when I try to access the admin panel, I'm getting an "Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)." When I check the console, I see a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'). Can you help me with this?
image 1
image 2
I thought it might be due to tag addition issues and deleted them, but the error persisted.
